# Is $\binom{py-1/2}{py}-\binom{y-1/2}{y}$ decreasing for $y\geq 1$?

Tags: special-functions

Fix $p\in(0,1)$ and consider the function $f:[1,+\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$

$f(y)=\binom{py-1/2}{py}-\binom{y-1/2}{y}$.

From numerical experimentation, it seems that this function is decreasing and convex.

Are there properties of the gamma function that can be exploited to prove such a statement?

Comment: Is it at all helpful to look at it as $\binom{py - 1/2}{-1/2} - \binom{y - 1/2}{-1/2}$, and to check the properties of the function $\binom{y - 1/2}{1/2}$?

Comment: @user44191 has a good point - one can then try to compute the derivative... Why 1/2 though? Perhaps start with an integer?

Comment: Take $p=1/8$. Then $f(y)$ is neither convex nor decreasing.